# Snappy video player settings?

Tags: video, video-player, gstreamer, clutter

[image]

[Snappy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/snappy/) is a small but robust gstreamer video player.

More:

http://luisbg.blogalia.com/historias/74484

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Snappy

https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/audio-and-video-in-ubuntu/snappy-video-player

http://youtu.be/x0t16HTo8YY

The apps.ubuntu displays it as "Powerful media player with a minimalistic interface", where "powerfull" may be an overstatement; but minimalistic it is indeed, so that I cannot access even the basic settings, although it is said to have subtitle support, increase speed etc.

There are the options displayed when running `snappy -h` in terminal. But can I access the options without terminal?

How to add subtitles?

Changing aspect ration would be great too.

---

I have discovered some keyboard options:

Q - quit

F - fullscreen

R - rotate

< - go to beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any help but the C source is just about readable for a novice. You want to look at the [`user_interface.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/snappy/tree/src/user_interface.c) file. You're looking for anything that uses `keyval`. You can see when it's being matched against `CLUTTER_...` keys and the comments help work out what it *does*.

For subtitles, <kbd>V</kbd> seems to be your key. [See ~L413](https://git.gnome.org/browse/snappy/tree/src/user_interface.c#n413):

```
case CLUTTER_v:
case CLUTTER_V:
{
  // toggle subtitles
  if (toggle_subtitles (ui->engine)) {
    gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_CLUTTER_TEXTURE
        (ui->subtitle_toggle),
        gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file (ui->subtitle_active_png, NULL), NULL);
  } else {
    gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_CLUTTER_TEXTURE
        (ui->subtitle_toggle),
        gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file (ui->subtitle_inactive_png, NULL),
        NULL);
  }

  handled = TRUE;
  break;
}
```

I can't see anything that suggests it would let you change the aspect. It merely displays in the same format as the source video.

Comment: Just pressing 'v' key while playing video does nothing. (By the way, that command works in VLC.) The author says 'More features accessible from Clutter interface'. What does that mean?

Comment: To me it means you can access more things directly from the graphical interface than you could before.

Comment: I see, the GUI was even more limited before.

Comment: Yes, the V key works if the subtitle is already loaded (for example through the option presented in my answer) in order to disable/enable it. But if the video is played already without subs, V key does nothing.

Comment: @cipricus I believe subtitles is an accessibility option. Does `--clutter-enable-accessibility` make a difference?

Comment: @mchid - what is to be done exactly? (I can enable subtitles with `-t` conveniently used in Nautilus actions as seen in my answer.)

Comment: In my case I created a python [script](https://github.com/felipsmartins/misc-and-code-snippets/blob/e918b089dffd391f082c3a7ca6bacb252b718f7b/Python/snappy.py) in order to detect subtitles when snappy player is started. Well I'll give a try modifying Snappy source code,

Answer (score 0):

Limited idea of an answer.

Maybe a way would be to use the terminal commands through the context menu, for example in Nautilus with Nautilus-Actions.

`snappy -h` says: `-t, --subtitles            Use this subtitle file`

So, then in nautilus-actions:

[image]

And limiting that to specific files

[image]

When selecting both the video and the subtitle file and right-clicking, the new nautilus action will start the video in Snappy with subtitles.

(But I don't think the display of the subtitles is editable. They look small and fuzzy.)

---

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/558777/47206) I have found these key commands:

```
Q - quit
F- toggle fullscreen
Space - play/pause
L - loop
8- mute
9, 0: double volume;
Up - Seek 1 minute foward
Down - Seek 1 minute back
Right - Seek 10 seconds foward
Left - Seek 10 seconds back
Page_Up - Seek 10 minutes foward
Page_Down - Seek 10 minutes back
R - rotate texture 90 degrees
C - show or hide controls
period - frame step forward
comma - frame step backward
V - toggle subtitles
J -cycle through available audio/text/video streams
o - switch display to time left of the stream
bracketright - get current rate
minus/plus - get current av_offset
```

(the V key works if the subtitle is already loaded (for example through the option presented in my answer) in order to disable/enable it. But if the video is played already without subs, V key does nothing)